# HTML & CSS blogger side menu?

Tags: jquery, html, css, blogger

In [this blog](http://bernardodamele.blogspot.pt/) you can see the menu on the right side?

I want a menu like that to a new project that I will start. And I can't find anything like this one.

I tryed to "Inspect Element" but blogger adds the CSS through "js" so we do not have one .css file to copy.

Any help?

Comment: I don't understand what is your question.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one, I used it and it's good.

Demo: [Demo](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/FixedNavigationTutorial/)

Page: [Page](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/11/30/beautiful-slide-out-navigation-a-css-and-jquery-tutorial/)

Comment: I don't like the design and when i click it disappears :(

Comment: You can change the design if you want, just alter the CSS. What do you mean it disappears ? On click it reloads the page because the anchors don't have a valid href.

Comment: I did not noticed that the page was reloaded (it was fast) :)