# HTML5/jQuery - Page Scroll to Input Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, input

I have a image document reader and in the header is an input[number] field. The idea is that the user can type which page (image) they'd like to see and the page will smoothly scroll down to the appropriate div.
Here's my code:

```
<div class="score-header">
    <section class="nav">
        <input type="number" id="page" />
    </section>    
</div>
```

The document's pages are displayed in their own divs, like so:

```
<div class="page-one">
    <img src="page1.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="page-two">
    <img src="page1.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

Is there a way that when the user inserts the number and clicks enter or a button, that the webpage will scroll down the the document's corresponding page.

N.B. The header sticks to the top of the webpage at all times via jQuery

Comment: why make user type a value instead of something they can click or touch? Doesn't seem very user friendly plus you need to validate whatever they enter

Comment: ...much simpler via select dropdown...?

Comment: the problem with those solutions is that if there are 65 pages your pretty screwed...

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#page').change(function() {
    $("page-div").eq($("#page").val()-1);
    //this selector takes the input value and subtracts 1 because the count starts in 0 so it will select the corect div ....

    //i do not know how to scroll down.... i tryed this but did not work.... you need scroll to the possition of the selected div
    $("#page-one").animate({scrollTop: $("#page-one").offset().top});
});
```

});
​

http://jsfiddle.net/ukjvS/13/

http://jsfiddle.net/ukjvS/13/show

(read the comments)

If possible answer my question :)

[HTML & CSS blogger side menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13897090/html-css-blogger-side-menu)